# Wrong canonical link

Tags: i18n-l10n, theming, uri

When I inspected the rendered source code of my page I noticed, that the canonical link is sort of broken, in that it has the language prefix doubled as in: `mysite.com/en/en/page.html`. When I click that link, the `mysite.com/en/en/page.html` opens correct, but its source code contains canonical link of `mysite.com/en/en/en/page.html` - and so on, and so on.
What could be the reason and is that something that could cause search engines' ban?

Comment: Are you using the Pathauto module?

Comment: Yes, indeed I am.